# SpringBoot, Hibernate and REST - date format in JSON

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, rest, spring-boot

I have a problem with date format in JSON response generated in REST project (SpringBoot+Hibernate).

When I call function I got JSON like this:

```
"rezerwacjaDataOd": 1535580000000,
"rezerwacjaDataDo": 1535839200000,
"rezerwacjaGodzOd": "14:00:00",
"rezerwacjaGodzDo": "12:00:00"
```

my entity:

```
private Date rezerwacjaDataOd;
private Date rezerwacjaDataDo;
private Time rezerwacjaGodzOd;
private Time rezerwacjaGodzDo;
```

It's Date from java.sql and Time from java.sql too

My controller:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("api/rezerwacja")
@Api
public class RezerwacjaController {
...
  @GetMapping(value = "/getRezerwacjaById")
  public @ResponseBody
  Rezerwacja getRezerwacjaById(Integer id) {
      return rezDao.findOne(id);
  }
...
```

Why Time is in "12:00:00" format, but Date in 1535580000000 format?
How to make Date to be in "yyyy-MM-dd" format?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should do two things

- add `spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps:false` in your `application.properties` this will disable converting dates to timestamps  and instead use a ISO-8601 compliant format
- You can then customize the format by annotating the getter method of you `dateOfBirth` property with `@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")`

Answer (score 0):

The differences in the way hibernate persists the date/time objects in the database have to do with the way these objects are used.

Per the documentation `Time` is a thin wrapper around `Date` that allows the underlying JPA provider to save the date object using the convention your noticed.

On the other hand, the `Date` object you pass in is converted directly to a timestamp and gets saved this way.

In both cases you can retrieve the value in question and serialize over to the desired format (with ISO-8601 being the best).

Another solution, other than the one mentioned above, is to create a custom serializer to do this.

A simple implementation would be:

```
public class Iso8601Serializer extends StdSerializer<Date> {

    private static final String ISO_8601_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";

    public Iso8601Serializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public Iso8601Serializer(Class clazz) {
        super(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider)
    throws IOException {
        if (date == null) {
            jsonGenerator.writeNull();
        } else {
            jsonGenerator.writeString(DateFormatUtils.format(date, ISO_8601_FORMAT));
        }
    }

}
```

Also (and this is a personal thing), I would advise in using plain `Date` objects to store dates and futhermore, have the respective fields annotated as `@Temporal`.